# Html link with multiple parameters send controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, href

I want to send 2 parameters in the following link? How can I do it? The idea?

```
var tarnsfer == true;
<a href="/Contacts/Register/' + row.ID + '" class="m-portlet__nav-link btn m-btn m-btn--hover-accent m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" title="Rehbere Taşı"><i class="la la-book"></i></a >
```

Controller;

```
public ActionResult Register(int id, bool tranfer)
      {


       }
```

Comment: is it a query string? use a url builder...

Comment: Please mind your spelling, `tarnsfer` is not the same name as `tranfer` and I guess **both** should be **`transfer`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tarnsfer == true;
<a href="/Contacts/Register?id=' + row.ID + '&transfer='+transfer" class="m-portlet__nav-link btn m-btn m-btn--hover-accent m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" title="Rehbere Taşı"><i class="la la-book"></i></a >
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use GET. Generate a link like this:

```
/Controllet/Register/?param_1=123&param_2=blahblahblah
```